# Writing a map<string int> to a file - no match for ‘operator<<’

Tags: c++

When I am compiling my C++ project, I get an error I don't understand. My error is thrown in this code section below:

```
void twogramsToFile(const map <string,int> twogram, const string outputfile) {
  ofstream myfile (outputfile);

  for (auto &x : twogram) {
    outputfile << x.first << " " << x.second << "\n"; //this line causes the error
  }

  myfile.close();
}
```

And the error message I get is this one:

```
no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ and ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’)
```

I thought the << operator was defined for the built in types.

Comment: *I thought the << operator was defined for the built in types* --  `<string>` is not built-in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought the << operator was defined for the built in types.

It isn't the right-hand side it's complaining about, but the left-hand side. You can stream *from* a const string, but you can't stream *into* a const string. Try

```
myfile << ...
```

Comment: And if you read the error message very carefully, it actually *says* that the arguments to `operator <<` are *both* `std::string`.

Comment: How do you stream from a string?

Comment: Using [`ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const string&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)

Answer (score 1):

You output to the string  outputFile. You should do:

```
myfile << ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to stream to a `const std::string`, I suspect it should be

```
myfile << x.first << " " << x.second << "\n";
```

instead of the `std::string` parameter `outputfile`.

Also you should pass the `std::map` and `std::string` by reference to avoid unnecessary copying as follows:

```
void twogramsToFile(const std::map<std::string, int>& twogram, const std::string& outputfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
outputfile << x.first << " " << x.second << "\n"; //this line causes the error
```

to:

```
myfile  << x.first << " " << x.second << "\n";
```

BTW, string is not builtin type in C++